egress window basement under beam
hey there would like to point out I'm not a profesional carpenter by any means. I do know I need an engineer before I go forward just trying get a basic idea of what needs to be acomplished and decide if I should go a different direction. Thanks in advanced.
I have a daylight basement my house is on a steep hill, 8 ft of elevation over 25' foundation. I have 1 room in basement I want to make 2 I need an egress window. To comply with 44" window sill from ground it makes my window fall right in line with the end of center beam. I am trying to figure out how to support beam with a post. Building the header above window won't work there is not enough space for a legal egress window. I have a hallway wall 48" from beam end. Is this possible, plausible, or any idea as most cost effective way to do this? I can't move into the room the window is going into without going below grade and excavation and drain expense. I don't wantt to move on other side of support as it will make 2nd bedroom too small. I included pics to help explain and show amount of current support in wall.
Beam is hard to see in pic but its 6.5" by 9" actual dimensions. It spans 35 ft and there is one post I have found 15 ft from end of beam where I want to place window.

The end of the beam needs support.  A steel beam header should be smaller in height than a wood beam header.  A bit of digging and a window well might help also.  Check also if having the egress window in the second room and a door between the two rooms would be allowed.  I know you need a second way to get out, but unknown if it needs to be direct to the outside.
